# Erro básico em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

bom dia galera, alguem sabe me dizer por que estou recebendo o erro

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list , na linha 14 no codigo a seguir:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var $div_novospedidos = $('#div_novospedidos');
      $div_novospedidos.empty(); //Limpando a tabela
      // setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
      $.get("database3.php", function(data, status) {
          //if (data == null) {console.log("sem pedidos hoje")} else {console.log("teste")};
          var dados_pedido = data;
          console.log(dados_pedido);
          const obj = dados_pedido;
        }

        var dados = $.parseJSON(data); console.log(dados); $.each(dados, function(i, item) {
          numeroPedido = item.doc_number;
          nomeCliente = item.client_name;
          horarioPedido = item.clock;

          var newReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 ">');
          var cols = "";

          cols += '<p>HORARIO: ' + horarioPedido + '</p></div>';
          cols += '<p>PEDIDO: ' + numeroPedido + '</p></div>';
          cols += '<p>Cliente: ' + nomeCliente + '</p></div>';

          newReq.append(cols);

          $("#div_novospedidos").append(newReq);

        });
      }
```

Comment: Tens um `}` perdido no código antes de `var dados`. E esse `. ready(` não está fechado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou fechar o trecho onde você faz o `$.get('database3.php', function (data, status) {`.

Apenas adicione o `)` antes do trecho que tem `var dados`. Também falta fechar com o `)` a última linha, ou seja, depois do último  `}` da função usada em `$(document).ready(function () {`;

Sugiro utilização de alguma IDE que você possa, em tempo real, verificar os erros de sintaxe, para que evite perda de tempos ou embarassos como esse.

Eu descobri fácil por estar usando o VS Code.

Veja:

[image: Checagem de Sintaxe no VSCODE]